# Como funciona o Select SUM(IF('',,'',''))

Tags: mysql, select, if

Pessoal estou apenas com uma duvida, sobre como funciona o select do mysql.

```
Select SUM(IF('','',''))
```

estou usando ela mas nao sei examente como ela funciona

Comment: Podes mostrar o que tens sff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagina o teu exemplo: `SUM(IF(debito_credito_financeiro = 'D', valor_financeiro, 0)) AS debito,`

A sintaxe é

> IF(condição,retorno se verdade,retorno se falso)

Ou seja, se `debito_credito_financeiro` tiver o valor de `D`, então ele vai somar o `valor_financeiro` senão, vai somar `0`.

Comment: "IF(debito_credito_financeiro = 'C', valor_financeiro, -valor_financeiro)" nesse caso o primeiro valor e positivo e o segundo negativo

Answer (score 1):

Digamos que eu queira contar quantas filiais em minha tabela de filiais tem o código maior do 20.

Eu poderia escrever:

```
select sum( if ( cod_filial > 21, 1, 0 )) from tabelafilais
```

ou quisesse contar quantos registros começam com 58 na tabela de locais:

```
select sum( if ( cod_local like '58%', 1, 0 )) from tabela_locais
```